# Best programming language for handling both statistical and spatial analysis

Tags: python, postgis, postgresql, r, software-recommendations

I am frequently involved in research where I do statistical programming and analysis using tabular datasets, and incorporate independent variables that have to be calculated in a GIS.  I currently rely on SAS for statistical programming and the ArcGIS GUI for obtaining the independent variables.  I face 2 challenges with this workflow.  First, I have to export my ArcGIS output and import it into SAS.  Second, I do not have a log of all the procedures I perform in the GIS.  As a result, my workflow is prone to errors because I am transfering data between systems and have no way to look back on my GIS steps.

**What are the best programming languages (and environments) for handling both the statistical and GIS analyses in one environment?**

**Preliminary Thoughts**

A partial solution would be to use Python with ArcPy.  I am not a fan of this solution because Python was not designed for statistical programming or statistical analysis.  I am wondering whether I should be looking into R or PostgreSQL with PostGIS.

Comment: http://www.scipy-lectures.org/packages/statistics/index.html

Answer (score 3):

Python clearly. [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/)/[GeoPandas](http://geopandas.org/) are established toolkit that has a lot of overlap between statistical and spatial analysis. R is indeed interesting, but I wouldn't want to use it for this. Think it more like Excel on steroids, I don't think it can work yet with datasets that don't fit into memory. Python is extensible and has far more packages. Further, it also has far more development gearing the language into the future. Just today in fact, [Google announced a project to transpile Python into Go](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=13319904) to take care of locking issues with the threading system.

I can't see any reason for R except for the use in academia. It's great at doing what it does, but so much of what it does is make things easy that's it doesn't really provide anything special.

Python is also the language on which to [extend and script QGis.](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/intro.html)

> Starting from 0.9 release, QGIS has optional scripting support using Python language. We’ve decided for Python as it’s one of the most favourite languages for scripting. PyQGIS bindings depend on SIP and PyQt4. The reason for using SIP instead of more widely used SWIG is that the whole QGIS code depends on Qt libraries. Python bindings for Qt (PyQt) are done also using SIP and this allows seamless integration of PyQGIS with PyQt.

Not to mention, Python, while not my favorite is pretty versatile and can be used to make web apps.

Comment: R does vastly more than you seem to realize.  @outsidethebox93 could take a look at the python statsmodels package and see if it's sufficient.

Comment: I'm in the local R User group. I do use R. I actually do not use python, but I've used in the past. I can't think of anything that R does better. Except simply graphing, and pulling in data. Even more complex stuff like non-blocking asynchronous io.. Python sucks at it but makes it easy. With R, it's almost impossible. And, when we say graphing I mean the easy stuff with BASE and GGplot. It's all dated stuff that should be done with d3.js and the like.

Comment: Just guessing, Python is more useful and difficult to learn. Haskell is probably the most succinct and terse, and difficult to learn. R is like the PHP of Academics that want to step away from Excel.

Comment: Although I appreciate your fervor, your answer highlights the importance of non-opinion based questions. R and Python are my bread and butter languages for work--each has their strengths and weaknesses. R is arguably one of the most capable languages for statistical programming period. Additionally, its package manager makes extending capabilities extremely easy. Working with spatial data in R is streamlined and easy to integrate into complex statistical routines such as machine learning. Python is easy to learn, has beautiful syntax, and can generally be considered a jack-of-all-trades.